# Map name of model object to a pg_search query param in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, pg-search

I have an `album` model, that has one 'cover_image' and has_many 'images'.  I also have a `product` model.  I am using pg_search to filter my products.

Independently, they both work flawlessly.  What I would like to do is show an albums `cover_image` based on the pg_search filter param.

For example: If I had a filter param called "limestone", I would create an album called "limestone" and when a user filters the page by limestone, they would get the product results along with the matching cover_image.

**product_controller - this works for filtering**

```
  def index
    @products = if params[:query]
                  Product.search_for(params[:query])
                else
                  Product.order(:name)
                end
  end
```

**product_controller - this breaks the page**
I tried this in an attempt to keep it simple and filter the image in the model

```
  def index
    @products = if params[:query]
                  Product.search_for(params[:query])
                  *@albums = Album.where(name:(params[:query]))*
                else
                  Product.order(:name)
                end
  end
```

**products/index.html.erb** Then I would just call the `album` as normal.

```
...
<% @albums.each do |a| %>
    <%= image_tag("#{a.cover_image_url(:original)}") %>
<% end %>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning `@albums` to `@products`. This is in effect what you're doing:

`@products = @albums = Album.where(name: (params[:query]))`

because the if statement is returning `@albums`. So this should work (assuming that the rest of your logic is correct):

```
def index
  @products = if params[:query]
                @albums = Album.where(name: params[:query])
                Product.search_for(params[:query])
              else
                Product.order(:name)
              end
end
```

However, I would not assign @albums where you are doing so right now. I think this is clearer thus *slightly* better:

```
def index
  if params[:query]
    @products = Product.search_for(params[:query])
    @albums   = Album.where(name: params[:query])
  else
    @products = Product.order(:name)
    @albums   = []
  end
end
```